# Memory leakage even though referencing binding to null

Tags: angular, service, memory-leaks

A reference to an @injectable Service is holding in to my Component even though I am setting the reference to null after done using the Service

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private yakService: YakService,
  private genericStateModel: GenericStateModel,
  private stateManagerQuery: StateManagerQuery,
  private stateManagerService: StateManagerService,
  public authenticationService: AuthenticationService
) {

}

public loadHerd(dataset?: number) {

  this.yakServiceSubscriptionLoadHerd = this.yakService.loadHerd(dataset).subscribe((data: YakItem[]) => {

    this.herdCollection = this.genericStateModel.herdData = data;

    const queryObject: QueryObject = _.cloneDeep(this.queryObject);
    queryObject.days = 0;
    queryObject.eventType = 'updateDays';
    this.stateManagerService.update(queryObject, 'queryObject');

    this.stateManagerService = null;
  });
}
```

Service

```
  @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
  export class StateManagerService {
    constructor(private stateManagerStore: StateManagerStore, private http: HttpClient) {}

    setActiveQueryObject(id: ID) {
      this.stateManagerStore.setActive(id);
    }

    update(queryObject: QueryObject, activeID: ID) {
      this.stateManagerStore.updateQueryObject(queryObject, activeID);
    }
  }
```

onDestroy

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  console.log('HerdComponent::ngDestroy');
  this.yakServiceSubscriptionLoadHerd.unsubscribe();
  this.yakServiceSubscriptionGetStock.unsubscribe();
  this.yakServiceSubscriptionGetHerd.unsubscribe();
  this.stateManagerSubcsription.unsubscribe();
  this.stateManagerService = null;
}
```

When i comment out `this.stateManagerService.update(queryObject, 'queryObject');` this line the Component is being Garbage Collected properly.

How to handle this?

Comment: Do you call this.yakServiceSubscriptionLoadHerd.usubscribe() in ngOnDestroy?

Comment: yes, but the issue is narrowed down to `this.stateManagerService` commented stuff out till I found out who the culprit is